# What is the Red Triangle next to the Ulti Diamond at the top of the UI

Tags: dota-2

So on the hero pictures at the top, there's a red triangle with the point placed down.  It's on the outside bottom of the top.  Also the same triangle appears on the large animaged profile picture when a hero is selected..

I stopped watching for 6 months, and I haven't been able to figure out what it's for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That badge means the player has reached level 1 to 5 of that hero's progression system, part of [Dota Plus subscription](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Dota_Plus).